# Mask ImageView with a shape

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is it possible to mask an `ImageView` with a shape such as a circle? I cant seem to figure out how to do this. I would ideally like to do this in the xml file.

Comment: Have you looked this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494603/custom-shape-of-imageview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom shapes xml files in the drawable folder, the call them as background in imageview.