# How to set the color of the circle image boundary in android?

Tags: android

I am fresher in android so I don't know how to set color of circle image boundary in android. Please can any one suggest me?

Comment: Explain in more details with what you tried yet.

Comment: did you mean circle draw in canvas ??

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hyu8.png on this circle image i want green boundary

Comment: Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527467/mask-imageview-with-round-corner-background , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881104/mask-imageview-with-a-shape

Comment: thanks @zapdroid my problem is solved with your this link

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to achieve the same thing.
1. Layering
2. Placing images inside a relative layout.

The example could be like below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_circle" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rotatetrans" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have created a project to demonstrate both approaches. you may consider taking a look at it.
Hope it helps.

https://github.com/gansBhat/AndroidProjects/tree/master/Examples/ImageWithBorder

Take a look at layout file
activity_main.xml

and ImageWithBorder\res\drawable\layeredImage.xml in the example. You can figure it out.